# Laravel E-commerce

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, e-commerce

I make laravel e-commerce project,
i have

- `categories` table who have `id`,`name`,`parent_id`,
- `characters` table who have `id`,`name`,
- `category_characters` table who have `id`,`category_id`,`character_id`,
- `products` table who have `id`,`name`,`category_id`,

I think I need some table who i can take him `product_id`,`category_characters_id`
whatever i can filterd the category page by product characters and when i add new product see categories characters.

- example: i select "phone" then i can take `phone_cpu`, `phone_ram`,
- example: i select "shoes" then i can take `shoes_size`, shoes_material,

and which Laravel relations i can do it

Comment: Hello, have you design the database schema?

Comment: I'am not sure to understand what you mean but you can use ManyToMany between Product and Character to achieve this..